# Is it possible to provide persisting data in a pypi package?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, pip, pypi, persistent-storage

I'm writing a python package which provides functionality to get data from a website and process it. After processing, it should remember this specific data  so that it doesn't try to process it again, even after restarting the script.

How would I implement saving this data persistently (by only saving an id)? I thought about providing a sqlite3 database file with my package. Would that be possible to access somehow? Or is there another, easier way that I don't see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to store data locally you can just serialise as a pickle object. Super fast read and writes would store the data between runs.
https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/pickle.html

```
with open('persist.p','wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(object,f)
```

```
with open('persist.p','rb') as f:
    object = pickle.load(f)
```

Python docs on persistence [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/persistence.html).

Comment: Thanks! I would process a lot of data concurrently, but only save the id's. Would pickle be the fastest choice in that case, or something like json?

Comment: In general pickle is faster than writing to JSON, but is only readable in Python, so depends if you want other software to be able to process. Pickles are not designed for concurrent access